# Trigger when scroll stopped by percent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger when user stop scrolling and alert some message. But I need to trigger it by percent.

For example I want to alert to user some message if he scroll, but when he stop scrolling and if he scroled more then 80% of window.

I have this code which trigger when srcoll is stopped and don't know how to get this work with scroll percen:

```
$.fn.scrollStopped = function(callback) {           
    $(this).scroll(function(){
        var self = this, $this = $(self);
        if ($this.data('scrollTimeout')) {
            clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
        }
        $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback,250,self));
    });
};

jQuery(window).scrollStopped(function(){
    alert('stopped');
});
```

Comment: I guess you will have to calculate the scrolled distance to the window's height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the height of document and window, and then compare it with the  current vertical position of the scroll bar:

```
$.fn.scrollStopped = function(callback) {           
    $(this).scroll(function(){
        var self = this, $this = $(self);
        if ($this.data('scrollTimeout')) {
            clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
        }
        $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback,250,self));
    });
};

jQuery(window).scrollStopped(function(){
    console.log(jQuery(window).scrollTop());
    if($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.8){
       alert('You have scrolled more than 80%');
    }

});
```

[Try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/bLfnU/). You probably want to read more details about both functions; [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) and [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/).

Answer (score 1):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/A9dB2/

```
jQuery(window).scrollStopped(function(){
    var docH = $(document).height();
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop()
    var totalPixels = docH - winH;

    var scrollPercentage = parseFloat(scrollTop/totalPixels * 100).toFixed(2);
    alert(scrollPercentage + "%");
});
```